# JDBC application hangs for bulk insert, when batch size is high

Tags: java, linux, unix, jdbc, bulkinsert

I am trying to do bulk insert from linux server(say server X) using simple JDBC application.

When I try the application with batch size of 5, it is working fine.

But when I try it with batch size of 500, it is hanging. I am not getting any error or exception. When I query the database, I could see the 500 rows are inserted but the java application just hangs. The java application is not exiting.

The application just hangs at the following method call

```
try{
// register driver

// establish connection

// create statement
// add insert commands from inputFile to the batch
statemnt.executeBatch();  //---------------application hangs here
}
//catch block followed by finally block to close resources
```

I tried the same application in different linux server, I was able to successfully execute the application for batch size of 500, the application ran fine and exited normally.

The application is hanging only in server X and only when the batch size is high.

Then I checked the strace of the hung process in server X. I found that it is looping in the following system calls

**$ strace -f -p [hung-java-process-id]**

```
[pid 104273] futex(0x7ffe78013728, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid 104273] clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {9635863, 882169546}) = 0
[pid 104273] clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {9635863, 882258933}) = 0
[pid 104273] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1417787058, 859159155}) = 0
[pid 104273] futex(0x7ffe78013754, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, {0, 49972845}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid 104273] futex(0x7ffe78013728, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid 104273] clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {9635863, 932601035}) = 0
[pid 104273] clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {9635863, 932677888}) = 0
[pid 104273] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1417787058, 909571241}) = 0
[pid 104273] futex(0x7ffe78013754, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, {0, 49977759}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid 104273] futex(0x7ffe78013728, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
```

I checked the list of open files opened by the hung java process and got the following output, which showed the db connection is still open.

**$ lsof -p [hung-java-process-id] | grep TCP**

```
COMMAND   PID       USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    104273 userid   14u  IPv6 1674188639      0t0  TCP serverX:55744->dbServer:blackjack (ESTABLISHED)
```

I also tried by setting connection AutoCommit property to false and then called commit after the executeBatch method. But still I am facing the same issue.

I also tried by splitting the batch with smaller batch size. The application is working fine upto batch size of 29 but when I increase the batch size to 30, it simply hangs without any error or exception.

I could not find the cause of the issue. 
If strace is showing the cause of the issue, then please let me know, what exactly does it mean and how to resolve it?
Any help would be much useful. Thanks in advance.

Please note I am using **Java 7**.

**I suppose the issue could be caused by some configuration in the linux machine(server X) as the same application is working fine in other machines for large batch size. Any insights related to the machine configuration would be very useful for me.**

Comment: I wonder if the connection is hijacked or force closed because of the long runtime? Is your connection pool timeout settings the same? And is there some kind of proxy to the DB server that may terminate connections?

Comment: you would prolly need to probably specify jdbc client and server, jvm versions. Hard to figure out why it is hanging/waiting on a resource.

Comment: what's the stack trace of the java application itself?

Comment: Linux server is Red Hat, Java  version 7, Database Teradata 14.10

Comment: @jtahlborn I am not getting any exception but the application hangs. I am calling the executeBatch method from main method.

Comment: yes i understand.  you can use various tools to dump the current thread stacks of a running java application.  this is generally far more useful than strace output.

Comment: Would you be able to split the batch of 500 into 100 batches of 5 for debugging? Just throwing this out there.

Comment: Perhaps you need to commit after the bulk insert?

Comment: @Compass I have edited my question as per your comments.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I have edited my question as per your comments.

Comment: We'll have to see the rest of your code and table structure.  If your table has foreign keys, that could be a problem, as if you are using large object blocks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

which database is it? I saw some mentions of problems with postgresql drivers, I have no idea whether similar issues happen on other providers.

See in [GitHub](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/194) and [PostGreSql](http://postgresql.nabble.com/JDBC-executeBatch-hangs-without-error-td5772465.html)

Comment: Database is Teradata 14.10